# Mouse events in NSMenuItem View with submenu

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I have menu which popped out after button click.

Add some items to menu and make first item submenu.

I want to handle the "select event" in all items and with standard menu all is fine.
But when i try to make custom View at NSMenuItem the submenu lost the ability to send events to action selector and custom NSView can't handle the mouseUp and mouseDown events.

Here my code to make all clear

```
#import "CRGAppDelegate.h"
@interface customItemView : NSView
{
    NSTrackingArea *_trackArea;
}
@end

@implementation customItemView

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1, 100)] fill];
    NSString* str = self.enclosingMenuItem.title;
    [str drawInRect:NSMakeRect(10, 4, 80, 22) withAttributes:nil];
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Mouse Down");
}
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Mouse Up");
}

-(void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    [self removeTrackingArea:_trackArea];
    _trackArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds] options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |
                                                                             NSTrackingActiveAlways |
                                                                             NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag
                                                                             ) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:_trackArea];
}
@end

@implementation CRGAppDelegate
{
    NSMenu* mainMenu;

}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    mainMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"mainMenu"];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        NSMenuItem* item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                      action:@selector(firstLevelItems:)
                                               keyEquivalent:@""];
        [item setView:[[customItemView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 30)]];
        [mainMenu addItem:item];

        if (i == 0)
        {
            //add submenu
            NSMenu* submenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submenu"];
            [item setSubmenu:submenu];
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                NSMenuItem* submenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"submenuitem"
                                                                     action:@selector(secondLevelItems:)
                                                              keyEquivalent:@""];
                [submenu addItem:submenuItem];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)secondLevelItems:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
}

-(void)firstLevelItems:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
}

- (IBAction)ExpandMenuAction:(id)sender {
    [mainMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:NSMakePoint(0, 35) inView:_OpenMenuButton];
}
@end
```

How can i receive select event in this case?

Comment: What is what you call 'select event'?

Comment: Some method which contains info about selected cell. Or the Mouse Up / Down method in view.